# Start Activity from RecyclerView.Adapter with bundled Object

Tags: android

I'm using RecyclerView to populate CardViews with my object "Income". Now I need one of the buttons in CardView to start new Activity and send that object to it.

Here's part of my button's onClickListener in Adapter:

```
  holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editAt(income);
        }
    });

public void editAt(Income income){
    Intent i = new Intent(context,IncomeAddActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    // here I want to send that "income" object

    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Is there any easy method to do this, or my approach is totally wrong?

Comment: I could try to bundle just a position and somehow send my List from parent Activity, but I have no idea if that's "good practise"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your class Income implements the interface Serializable. Then you can do this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("object", income);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use Shared Preferences to store and get some data

```
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
         ed.putInt("view_mode", mCurViewMode);
         ed.commit();
```